# Porfavor una solución con este error a la hora de usar el comando clean and build en el NetBeans me salta el error de la imagen

Tags: java, netbeans, windows, github, cmd

Hola amigos estoy en la Universidad viendo programación orientada a objetos además trabajamos con un repositorio de GitHub y estamos iniciando a crear un proyecto en NetBeans la cuestion es la siguiente: He creado un proyecto de java aplication y procedi a hacer un codigo muy simple, el código me corre normalmente entonces entro a la consola de comando mi Windows10 y accedo a la carpeta de mi repositorio donde guardo mi proyecto para subirlo una vez finalizado pero debo entrar hasta la carpeta "build" para aplicar el comando java nombre_de_mi_proyecto.class en la consola y eso obviamente me salta un error porque me falta hacer en el NetBeans el comando clean and build y justo ahí me salta el error no se ejecuta ese comando y no se como arreglarlo ya he desinstalado el netbeans alguna solucion ?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Simple: abre ese directorio y si es de esos temporales, bórralo. La otra opción es que ejecutes NetBeans como administrador.

Comment: podrias enseñarme como porfavor

Comment: En el ícono del netbeans, click derecho, ejecutar como administrador. O inicio, buscas "netbeans", pones el mouse encima, "más", seleccionas la opción "ejecutar como administrador".

Comment: y la primera opcion como la ejecuto?

Comment: Aquí https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=como+ejecutar+como+administrador+en+windows+10